# Difference in Linux and Windows JDBC Timestamp precision?

Tags: java, linux, windows, jdbc

Is there a difference in actual precision of a `java.sql.Timestamp` when loaded via windows jdbc or linux jdbc from, lets say oracle `timestamp(9)`. Are there different behaviors/precisions in different drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html) has nanosecond precision:

> A thin wrapper around `java.util.Date` that allows the JDBC API to
>   identify this as an SQL `TIMESTAMP` value. It adds the ability to hold
>   the SQL `TIMESTAMP` fractional seconds value, by allowing the
>   specification of fractional seconds to a precision of nanoseconds.

Given Java is platform-independent, this precision is the same on Windows or Linux. However, different platforms can have different resolution timers, so values created on those platforms may have lower precision (sometimes depending on BIOS and/or OS settings) for the actual values generated.

As database systems have different resolutions for their timestamp types (and sometimes multiple timestamp-like types with different precision), the actual available precision will depend on the database system and type used (and sometimes on the specific JDBC driver implementation). It is far too broad to cover all options here though.